# SQL Server : two rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have code in SQL Server 2008 and I need to join a row in another.

This is the code

```
select
    usuario.SK_Representative,
    sum(devo.NM_Material) as deve
from 
    DW_DTS_Representative usuario
inner join 
    DIS_DTS_Sales_Return_Fact devo on devo.SK_Representative = usuario.SK_Representative
inner join 
    DW_DTS_Operation_Nature cfop on cfop.SK_Operation_Nature = devo.SK_Operation_Nature
inner join 
    DW_DTS_Emitter cli on cli.SK_Emitter = devo.SK_Emitter
where
    devo.CD_Currency = '0'
    and devo.CD_Site = '001'
    and cli.CD_Customer_Group = '10'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '2'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '3'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '4'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '41'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '48'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '49'
    and usuario.SK_Representative != '43'
    and devo.DT_Day between DateAdd(yyyy, DateDiff(yyyy,0,GetDate()), 0) 
                        and dateadd([month], datediff([month], '18991231', dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), '18991231')
group by 
    usuario.SK_Representative
```

The result of that script is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pOIc.jpg)

But I need to aggregate the SK_Representative information for the number '33' into the SK_Representative for the number '47'. I need to do this without losing the primary key which is the SK_Representative.

Comment: That is current result or desire output?

Comment: What you mean " aggregate the SK_Representative information for the number '33' into the SK_Representative for the number '47'"

Comment: The 'deve' value of SK_Representative '33' must be summed with 'deve' of SK_Representative '47'

Comment: The current result its the image in the question

Comment: The desire result is not to show SK_Representative number '33' and the value 'deve' of him most go to SK_Representative number '47'

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza but I need an urgent response to my question, in my opinion I know that I made my question very clear.

Comment: Well good luck with that. Good question are usually answer in minutes. But if you don't take the time to make a proper question why we waste our time trying to understand it. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: btw instead of multiple and just use `NOT IN` like `and usuario.SK_Representative NOT IN ( '2', '3', '4', '41', '48', '49', '43')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this is what you want. I have also taken into account @juan-carlos-oropeza's suggestion for using `usuario.SK_Representative NOT IN`.

```
select
    CASE
        WHEN usuario.SK_Representative IN ('33', '47') THEN '47'
        ELSE usuario.SK_Representative
    END AS SK_Representative,
    sum(devo.NM_Material) as deve
from 
    DW_DTS_Representative usuario
inner join 
    DIS_DTS_Sales_Return_Fact devo on devo.SK_Representative = usuario.SK_Representative
inner join 
    DW_DTS_Operation_Nature cfop on cfop.SK_Operation_Nature = devo.SK_Operation_Nature
inner join 
    DW_DTS_Emitter cli on cli.SK_Emitter = devo.SK_Emitter
where
    devo.CD_Currency = '0'
    and devo.CD_Site = '001'
    and cli.CD_Customer_Group = '10'
    AND usuario.SK_Representative NOT IN ('2', '3', '4', '41', '48', '49', '43')
    and devo.DT_Day between DateAdd(yyyy, DateDiff(yyyy,0,GetDate()), 0) 
                        and dateadd([month], datediff([month], '18991231', dateadd(month, -1, getdate())), '18991231')
group by 
    CASE
        WHEN usuario.SK_Representative IN ('33', '47') THEN '47'
        ELSE usuario.SK_Representative
    END AS SK_Representative
```

Hope this gets you going on the right path.

Noel

Comment: It worked, but I removed the alias from the last case of your code.Thanks Guys !